# Need to display large table positioned to row that has td with cerain text

Tags: jquery, html, contains

I have a large html table.  I need to allow the user to type a letter or two then position the first row that is prefixed by that text and scroll to that element.

I have searched and demo'd all the relative posts ( I think ) but cannot find anything close.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vaughn/xY7tx/2654/)

```
<script>
var container = $('div'),
    scrollTo = $('#row_8');

container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
</script>

<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style

<div>
    <table id="my_table">
        <tr id='row_1'><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_2'><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_3'><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_4'><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_5'><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_6'><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_7'><td>7</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_8'><td>8</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_9'><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_10'><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_11'><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_12'><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_13'><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_14'><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_15'><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_16'><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_17'><td>17</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_18'><td>18</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_19'><td>19</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_20'><td>20</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_21'><td>21</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_22'><td>22</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_23'><td>23</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_24'><td>24</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_25'><td>25</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_26'><td>26</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_27'><td>27</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_28'><td>28</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_29'><td>29</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_30'><td>30</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_31'><td>31</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_32'><td>32</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_33'><td>33</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_34'><td>34</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_35'><td>35</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_36'><td>36</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_37'><td>37</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_38'><td>38</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_39'><td>39</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_40'><td>40</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_41'><td>41</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_42'><td>42</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_43'><td>43</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_44'><td>44</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_45'><td>45</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_46'><td>46</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_47'><td>47</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_48'><td>48</td></tr>
        <tr id='row_49'><td>49</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try writing some code, and then rewrite your question detailing what you have tried, why it isn't working, and what code snippets are giving you trouble. You'll receive a much more constructive answer that way. In it's current form it is way too broad a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may suggest you to use an input text box to insert the first one or two chars and then scroll down to that row, if it exists (how to organize this is up to you, this is only an idea):

The following line:

```
 var row = $('table').find('tr').filter(function(index, element) {
  return $(element).text().trim().startsWith(c);
}).first();
```

selects the first row having a text starting with the string you typed (one char if it contains only one char). For text I intend the whole row text: cell1 text + cell1 text + ...  So in this way you compare just against the first chars (one or two or more) you typed.
If this row does not exist do nothing.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#iGoTo').on('input', function(e) {
    var c = this.value
    var row = $('table').find('tr').filter(function(index, element) {
      return $(element).text().trim().startsWith(c);
    }).first();
    if (row.length == 1) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: row.offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

Goto row: <input id="iGoTo" type="text" maxlength="2"/>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>14Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>18Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>23Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>25Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>26Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>27Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>28Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>29Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>30Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect.  With minor changes it works just as I need it to.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with --  var row = $('table').find('tr').filter(function(index, element) {
      return $(element).text().trim().startsWith(c);
    }).first();

The length is always 1 and if I alert(row) I get object(object).  Also the code is case sensitive.  I'm working on that.

Comment: If I enter an "e" it scrolls down to show the 2 entries that start with an "E".  So,  case sensitivity doesn't appear to be a problem now.  But If I enter an "m" it only scrolls down a tiny bit.  If I backspace it scrolls back up.  The same thing for the letter "t".  Some other letters don't  do a thing.  I;m trying to debug using Firebug but I might have to "un-minimize" the code.

Comment: @user990016 Answer updated with an additional explanation on how the filter function works.